# How to call SSRS URL request

Tags: javascript, ajax, reporting-services

Is there any way to make SSRS URL requests from my JavaScript AJAX code to get the list of folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar problem in the past. You need to use [ReportExecution service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.aspx) (reportexecution2005.asmx) or   [ReportService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (reportservice2005.asmx)

The difference between the two is that the first one allows you to render reports, while the second one allows you to manipulate folders/files on the report server.
ReportService2005.asmx has a method called `ListChildren()` which I was able to use successfully from C#.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am able to use 'http://localhost/reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx/' to get folders from web browser but I need get if from my javascript code which I did not know how to use the ajax call.